# Mockito. How to return a boolean value based on mocked object as parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
Class A
{
public B makeB(int q)
    {
        return new B(q);
    }
    public boolean evaluate(int q)
    {
        B b = makeB(q);
        boolean result = b.get();
        return result;
    }
}

Class B
{
    int e;
    public B(int w)
    {
        e=w;
    }
    public boolean get()
    {
        //return boolean based on object B
    } 
}

Class ATest
{
    A a = spy(A.class);
    B b1 = mock(B.class);
    B b2 = mock(B.class);

    doReturn(b1).when(a).makeB(5);
    doReturn(b2).when(a).makeB(10);

    when(b1.get()).thenReturn(true);
    when(b2.get()).thenReturn(false);

    a.evaluate();
}
```

=======================

Here I would like to return true from method evaluate when object B contains value 5 and false if it contains value 10.

Class B is from an external Library.

New to unit testing and mockito.

Comment: use an if else statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are technically correct, but the **first** thing to understand: you should strive to *not* use a mocking framework like this.

Keep in mind: the purpose of a mocking framework is *only* to make testing possible/easier. Your mocking specs should be as simple as possible. Meaning: instead of thinking about having a mock giving different results on different parameters - the better solution is to have *distinct* tests and mocking specs, like:

```
@Test 
public void testFooWithA() {
  when(someMock.foo(eq(whateverA)).thenReturn(bar);
  ...

@Test 
public void testFooWithB() {
  when(someMock.foo(eq(whateverB)).thenReturn(somethingElse);
  ...
```

There are situations where you have write more sophisticated code to make your mocks "more smart". But most of the time when I had to do that - I stepped backed, and *simplified* my design under test. In other words: when your tests turn "too complicated" - most often the reason is a **too complicated** class/method under test.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Mockito's `Answer` interface. It gives you access to call's actual arguments and you can differentiate returned value based on that.

Given interface

```
interface Measurer {
    int measureLength(String s);
}
```

an example usage could look like

```
Measurer measurer = Mockito.mock(Measurer.class);
Mockito.when(measurer.measureLength(Mockito.any(String.class)))
        .then((Answer<Integer>) invocationOnMock -> {
            String arg = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
            if (arg.length() < 10) {
                // mock Measurer can measure only short strings
                return arg.length();
            }
            else {
                return 42;
            }
        });

System.out.println(measurer.measureLength("abc")); // 3
System.out.println(measurer.measureLength("abcdefghijklmn")); // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could do:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
     public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
         return invocation.getArgument(0) == 5;
     }}).when(a.evaluate());
```

If you're asking how to get the actual value of 'b' inside the actual implementation of A#evaluate(), then you could add an answer for makeB for both mocks that set a local variable to the instance of B that is returned, so you know what it returned the last time it was called, then you could have your answer for evaluate() return based on the value of that local variable.

That is:

```
B lastB = null;
Answer<B> lastBAnswer = new Answer<B>() {
  public B answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    if (invocation.<Integer>getArgument(0) == 5) {
      lastB = b1;
    } else {
      lastB = b2;
    }
    return lastB;
  }
};
doAnswer(lastBAnswer).when(a).makeB(any());
doAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    return lastB.get();
  }
}).when(a).evaluate();
```

I wouldn't recommend that path though, as it relies on temporal cohesion, but for testing it could be acceptable.

Note: Answering through StackOverflow without syntax checking this. Could be slightly off, but this is the rough idea.